# Question about Salesforce limits on API Callouts

Tags: callout, webservices, governorlimits

I have to call a webservice from an external system each time a new record is created on Salesforce.
The external webservice accepts a single record/object instance per callout.

If I do an after-insert bulk trigger, how will I do the callouts per record?
Is doing callouts in a *for* loop advisable?

If many records are created at the same time, will I hit the callout limits?
I see only 100 callouts allowed per transaction.

Any other suggestion on this? Continuation? Queueable?

Thank you.

Comment: I like the Appleman advanced apex async pattern for this - you write all your callout requests to an `async_request__c` object and these get processed serially via chained queueables with fallback to future/schedulable. If the callout fails, you have a built-in way to replay. see his book - chapter 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queueable is the go-to way to do this today. You can make up to 100 callouts, then chain until you're done.

```
public class MyQueueable implements Database.AllowsCallouts, Queueable {
  public MyQueueable(Set<Id> recordIds) {
    this.recordIds = recordIds;
  }
  Set<Id> recordIds;
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    Map<Id, sObject> records = new Map<id, sObject>([
      SELECT Fields FROM myObject__c WHERE Id = :recordIds
    ]);
    while(Limits.getCallouts() < Limits.getLimitCallouts() && recordIds.size() > 0) {
      doCalloutWith(records.get(recordids.remove(0));
    }
    if(recordIds.size() > 0) {
      System.enqueueJob(this); // Go again!
    }
  }
}
```

To call this:

```
System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(Trigger.newMap.keySet()));
```

Note that this code is future-proof; if the limits change, this code will automatically adapt to those changes.

Note also that this is a basic design, you should add error handling and retry capabilities, if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. What if the external system decides to accept a list of record instead of one single instance? Do I still opt for Queueable? Or a simple bulk trigger + @future method for callouts will be enough in terms of limits etc.?

Comment: @S.. Future methods can work if you can get the remote end to accept lists, though I'd still recommend a Queueable, because you can use the a [transaction finalizer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm) to deal with governor limits, etc. It also depends on how much data you need to send; you can only send up to 12 MB of data per transaction, so you might need to split across multiple transactions anyways.

Comment: thank you so much for the details. It's not much data, only have to send some basic text fields. I wanted to know the good way of implementing it. Going for bulk trigger with Queueable class. Thanks again for your help.